# Unable to make picture follow mouse using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I've been tying to learn JavaScript by following a few tutorials on YouTube. I want a picture to follow the cursors movement. When i launch the site it takes a really long time to load. When it's finally done, nothing happens.  This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
<section id="main">
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
Upgrade to a modern browser
</canvas>
</section>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Animation.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        AN.initialize();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var AN = AN || {};

pic = new Image();

AN.initialize = function()
{
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", An.moveMouse, false);

    cv = $('#canvas')[0];
    canvas = cv.getContext('2d');

    pic.src = "pictures/test.png";
};

AN.moveMouse = function(e)
{
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    var xPos = e.clientX;
    var ypos = e.clientY;

    canvas.drawImage(pic, xPos, yPos, pic.width, pic.height);
};
```

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery for event handling?

Comment: Yes. And telling us what errors you're seeing in the console, if any, would be useful